# How to get specific frame from a video in Java

Tags: java, video, codec

I'm looking for a way to retrieve a specific frame from a video in Java. For example, `get frame #198 from movie.mp4`. I do not need it to be MP4 specific, as a long as the solution works on a common video file type. I've seen libraries for this, such as Xuggle and JCodec, but as they are older there are issues with support; the JCodec JAR doesn't even contain one of the classes necessary to store a frame. JCodec does not, without modification of the JAR, support grabbing a single frame from a file. Other libraries require looping to get to a specific frame. I'd like to just have a method call that will return a specific frame.

Comment: @Berger the solution for that question uses a JCodec example that involves deprecated code and the other answer to that question is not retrieving a specific frame

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV will allow you do this using the 'OpenCVFrameGrabber' class.

Its documented here: http://bytedeco.org/javacv/apidocs/org/bytedeco/javacv/OpenCVFrameGrabber.html

You can either iterate through the file, or if you want to avoid this as you indicate, you can set the frame which the capture should occur at using the 'setFrameNumber' method of the class.

One thing to watch out for - the openCV fame number setting reportedly will just go to the nearest Iframe if the video is encoded this way. I have not tested this so cannot confirm but one way around this problem is to seek to a position before but near the desired frame and then iterate for the final few frames to get the positions you want and then use the frame grabber.

Comment: openCV... to get  a frame...ok